# MCUDA installation instructions

Tags: cuda

The website and README file that come with the MCUDA package, provide no instructions on how to install it and I ran into a problem.  I simply do not know what "library and final source code compiler for MCUDA" refers to.

```
# install.sh
Desired MCUDA install path (/MCUDA appended): /usr/local
Existing CUDA installation directory path: /usr/local/cuda/
Choice of MCUDA library (omp/pthread/serial): 
Library and final source code compiler for MCUDA: 


Confirm setup parameters...............................
MCUDA will be installed to: /usr/local
CUDA is installed in: /usr/local/cuda/
MCUDA library implementation: 
Path to MCUDA library and application compiler: 
Confirm (y/n): y
Verifying setup parameters...
Error: unsupported MCUDA library implementation ""
```

Answer (score 2):

The error presented in your posting is actually that you did not specify one of the library methods for MCUDA to take advantage of the CPU.  You must specify `omp` or `pthreads` or `serial` when prompted, otherwise you'll get that error.  But to answer your question, the next prompt asks `Library and final source code compiler for MCUDA:`

Remember MCUDA is a source-to-source translator.  Ultimately it's purpose is to take cuda C source code and make it compilable and runnable on the CPU (only).  So this question is asking "what cpu compiler do you want to use?"  I believe that the only compiler this tool is really set up for is icc (intel c compiler) however.  So if you don't have icc you are going to be struggling with it.
If you have icc (and it is on your PATH), just enter `icc` when prompted for `Library and final source code compiler for MCUDA:`

Note that MCUDA requires root privileges (generally) to install correctly, and it has the potential to modify your cuda installation.

Also note that MCUDA has a variety of limitations (e.g. cannot handle c++ code) as outlined in the README.